# AngularJS Get current factory/service name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Ola!

I was just playing around with angular's factories and services and I just noticed
that I can't get the current name of the factory/service. 
At least I couldn't get any resources about that.
For example so its a bit more clear I have a factory, like this;

```
.factory('GuessImAFactory', [function() {

    var factoryName = this.yadayada.name; //<- This actually doesn't work,
                                             //if you haven't guessed

    //<--Some other code goes here-->

    return something;
}])
```

So the question does anyone know the trick how to get the name of it?

Comment: what is the use case that it would benefit you to have a name?

Comment: Does it really matter? :) The thing is I am repeating that string like 3 times in one factory and I have like 200 factories, it would save me some typing and also re-factoring would be a nightmare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. In callback function you can't get actual instance of factory since you are defining it right in that place. In other works, it's not yet created.

However, simple workaround for this would be to hard code it.. Since you probably won't have dynamic factories, you could just simply say

```
var factoryName = 'GuessImAFactory';
```

and use it if needed.

Comment: Thought something like that was the case... Kinda feared this was the only solution :/

Answer (score -1):

Try this one: `factoryObject.__proto__.constructor.name`